# android public textbox

Tags: android, tabs, public

I have come across another prickly little problem.

I am writing an app with tabs, but I have a textbox (EditText) at the top of the screen that I want to be able to receive text data from any of the tabs.  As each of the tabs has it's own activity and layout, this is proving difficult to achieve.

I want to be able to use:

```
editText1.setText("Hello World");//sample text
```

from any Tab/Activity.

Does anyone know how to make a textbox from one layout public and able to recieve text?

I am using TabActivity, yes I know it's deprecated but as this is my first app with tabs, it's easier to learn than Fragments.  I will try them next time, unless they are the answer to my problem, in which case I have a lot of re-coding to do!!

ok, new part.

```
package com.epsilonitsystems.epecsandroid;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

public EditText editText1;  


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Core
    TabSpec corespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Core");
    corespec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_i));
    Intent coreIntent = new Intent(this, CoreActivity.class);
    corespec.setContent(coreIntent);

    // Tab for Drink
    TabSpec drinkspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Drink");
    drinkspec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_drink));
    Intent drinkIntent = new Intent(this, DrinkActivity.class);
    drinkspec.setContent(drinkIntent);


    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(corespec); // Adding Core tab    
    tabHost.addTab(drinkspec); // Adding Drink tab  
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

That's the Main Activity, I'll just show the Core Activity as they will all be the same when I get it working.

```
package com.epsilonitsystems.epecsandroid;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

public class CoreActivity extends Activity {

private TextToSpeech mTts;
// This code can be any value you want, its just a checksum.
private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1234;

EditText editText1;
String Spch,Str;
ImageButton imageButton1,imageButton2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.core_layout);

    //button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, null);

}

public void onimageButton1Click(View view) {
//mTts.speak("I",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
//Spch=editText1.toString();
//Spch=Spch+"I ";

    editText1.setText("Hello World");
}


}//Activity End
```

I can't post a screenshot as I'm still a new user, sorry.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Gary,

What you are looking for probably is how to share data between different Activities. 
You can do this in a couple of ways, but the cleanest is using the Intent you start the new Activity with. 
With this you can set extra data via the Intent.putXXXXX methods. 
You could use something as Intent.putExtra("my_private_key", mTextVar); and fetch that out in your other Activity with this.getIntent().getStringExtra("my_private_key");

ps. As tempting as it might seem to start with the TabActivity, you're actually making it a lot more difficult for yourself by making a bad start and learning classes which you should not use anymore. I'd advise you to pick up some good fragments tutorials which will be just as easy once correctly explained. You should take a look at per example http://www.vogella.com/android.html

Comment: Hi Stefan, I will take onboard the advice about TabActivity, thank you.  As for using the Intent I start the Activity with, I don't think that's going to cure my problem.  I need to be able to add text to the textbox when the user presses buttons in any of the tabs. I am writing a communication program for kids and they press buttons with symbols on them to build a sentence.  The different words are categorised in the different tabs.

Comment: Gary,
Perhaps some parts of your code and/or a screenshot of your app will make things a bit more clear. As far as I understand from your comment you simply want a bunch of buttons at the top of your screen that append text to a textfield. Why not just use (styled) buttons for that then?